# MongoDB, Node, Express, EJS - Pass a array/variable from backend to frontend (from route to client)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I've been trying to figure out a better way to push a variable from the backend to the frontend. Right now I do something like this.

I have a MVC-pattern, so when hitting the route

```
app.get('/fil', middleWare.isLoggedIn, user.fil)
```

... trough node does some querying the DB, and pass on the data.

```
exports.fil = async (req, res) => {

    try {

        faktura = await Lan.find().populate('client', 'namn kundnr')

        res.status(200).render('pages/createInvoice', {
            faktura: faktura
        });

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving datas."
        });
    };
};
```

... it generates the page, with the help of EJS (i love EJS) and then pass it on to the client/user.

And in the .ejs-file that is served to the client/user I add the following

```
<script>
    var fakturor = <%- JSON.stringify(faktura) %>;
</script>
```

which then means that I use up the variable and work with it with JS.

And this is where my question pops up. Is this a good way to do it or is there any other way to handle it?

I guess one idea is to let the user to query the DB straight from the page, but in my case I believe it wouldn't actually be better for the user to do so (the user will reieve like 100 different rows that they will be able to filter and then download a file of)

But is there any other ways I could do this without the script-tag? Like i said, I guess a ajax-call from JS/the client could be used but could you do it any other way? Can EJS do it any other way?

Comment: use response.json and send a Json obejct containing the payload you want to send

Comment: @INDRESHKHANDELWAL, care to elaborate? response.json?

Comment: response.json() takes a json object and sends it the requested http request.So if lets say you want to send a variable x then it can be done in this way => response.json({x: value})

Comment: Hmm. I´ll check that out. Thank you for the information. 

You don't happen to have a good link where I can read up on it?

Answer (score 1):

ejs is used for static pages mainly, if you want to build a dynamic page I would look for a single page application framework like angular and react.
if you still want to use ejs you can use ajax call to the server to load a variable from the DB.
I would never query directly from Front end to DB because then you are not controlling the security of the server, always go through the BE.

- also try to think if you really need a variable in the front end, can you solve your problem using rendering only?

Comment: I'm not really interested in building a SPA:s as I deem it to be overkill for my smaller projects. I could be wrong though. 

The idea of ajax-call trough the BE is what I've so far gathered as a possibility, and I guess I´ll check it out. The thing is that, I pass the array, then the user can do some changes to it and then "save" it, as an array. 

It then saves this to DB, but also copy the array > xml nd the user get prompted if the want to dload the file. 


Im not sure how I could solve the part where users can change stuff if theres is no array passed on from the BE.